# I have Issue in this Code TypeError: Only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`),

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I Have issue in this code. i get error Only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`) . Tell me how to fix this. How to pass data in preprocess_image

```
File "<ipython-input-4-510e647f5cff>", line 7, in preprocess_image  *
    height = tf.cast(tf.shape(data["image"])[0], dtype=tf.float32)

TypeError: Only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), tf.newaxis (`None`) and scalar tf.int32/tf.int64 tensors are valid indices, got 'image'
```

```
def round_to_int(float_value):
    return tf.cast(tf.math.round(float_value), dtype=tf.int32)


def preprocess_image(data):
    # unnormalize bounding box coordinates
    height = tf.cast(tf.shape(data["image"])[0], dtype=tf.float32)
    width = tf.cast(tf.shape(data["image"])[1], dtype=tf.float32)
    bounding_box = data["bbox"] * tf.stack([height, width, height, width])

    # calculate center and length of longer side, add padding
    target_center_y = 0.5 * (bounding_box[0] + bounding_box[2])
    target_center_x = 0.5 * (bounding_box[1] + bounding_box[3])
    target_size = tf.maximum(
        (1.0 + padding) * (bounding_box[2] - bounding_box[0]),
        (1.0 + padding) * (bounding_box[3] - bounding_box[1]),
    )

    # modify crop size to fit into image
    target_height = tf.reduce_min(
        [target_size, 2.0 * target_center_y, 2.0 * (height - target_center_y)]
    )
    target_width = tf.reduce_min(
        [target_size, 2.0 * target_center_x, 2.0 * (width - target_center_x)]
    )

    # crop image
    image = tf.image.crop_to_bounding_box(
        data["image"],
        offset_height=round_to_int(target_center_y - 0.5 * target_height),
        offset_width=round_to_int(target_center_x - 0.5 * target_width),
        target_height=round_to_int(target_height),
        target_width=round_to_int(target_width),
    )

    # resize and clip
    # for image downsampling, area interpolation is the preferred method
    image = tf.image.resize(
        image, size=[image_size, image_size], method=tf.image.ResizeMethod.AREA
    )
    return tf.clip_by_value(image / 255.0, 0.0, 1.0)

train = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    r'/content/drive/MyDrive/datasetnew',
    label_mode=None,
    validation_split=None,
    image_size=(64, 64),
    shuffle=True,
    seed=123,
    batch_size = 20,
   
).map(preprocess_image, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
```

Comment: What shape and type is your `data`? The error states that `["image"]` is not a valid index.

Comment: BatchDataSet(None, 64, 64, 3), types: tf.float32>

Comment: It seems that your `data` is already an image. To get height and width, you could try
`height = tf.cast(data.get_shape()[1], tf.float32)`
`width = tf.cast(data.get_shape()[2], tf.float32)`

Comment: bounding_box = data["bbox"] * tf.stack([height, width, height, width]) Again error in this line

Comment: How did you create your data? What should it contain?

Comment: Bascially Its WSI Cancer tissues dataset. I will do Data augmentation With GAN I had picked this code from Keras. I will try to generate images with augmentation, But I have issue in load own dataset. I  Tried tensower flow data set, its working fine, Please help in this beacuse i am working on research work. I had try search on google but failed.  Code: Link https://keras.io/examples/generative/gan_ada/

Comment: If you look at the example link, you can find the dataset the example uses [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/catalog/caltech_birds2011). The features are in a dictionary. If you want to use the same code, you have to create your dataset to be similar, or modify the code to work with your own exact data.